# Import function with curly brackets

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Not sure what it means when we include function within curly brackets. Can you tell the difference between the following two lines?

```
import {sportsPage} from 'sports-page';

import sportsPage from 'sports-page';
```

Comment: Isn't this just normal JS `import` semantics? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: @all why did you guys mark it negative...I didn't know that's the reason I asked

Comment: I can't answer for whoever downvoted, but probably because the answer is pure JS, and relatively easy to find out.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am beginner very new to js and programming :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good read on ES6 modules: https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/

The difference between those two, is that brackets `{}` are used when you are not exporting a `default` module. You can't rename them!

Without brackets, the exported function, variable, etc needs to be a `default`. You can name `myFunction` whatever you like.

```
export default myFunction;

...

import somethingsomethingDangerZone from "myfunction.js";
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation...really nice article https://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/